# SQL Server 2008/2012 Peer-to-Peer Replication - Configure Speed

Tags: performance, sql-server-2008, replication, sql-server-2012

I've setup a sample Peer-to-Peer replication test in SQL Server 2012, and I've bulk inserted 3 million rows in one of the nodes.

Replication is working... but it seems to be throttled at 100 inserts per second. Both servers are basically sitting idle.

Is there any way to configure the log-reader / distributor to go faster... aka, try 1000 at a time, etc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try increasing the Distribution Agent parameter **-CommitBatchSize** and see if that helps.  The default is 100, try bumping it up to 1000.

[Replication Distribution Agent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms147328.aspx)

Comment: I'm doing this through the GUI - is there an easy "right-click here and press 'Options'" to do this?

Comment: Found it... right-click on "Local Publications" and choose "Configure Distribution..."